# Is it possible to create an EJB dedicated to managing EJB 3.1 timers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1

This might be a stupid question, but would it be possible to dedicate an EJB to managing all the timers for the entire container? I don't know how this would be accomplished as I'm not all that experienced with Java EE, but I'm thinking something along the lines of individual session beans having access to this timer bean, and the session beans pass in a function pointer along with the meta data for the job itself? On top of the timer bean, it would then be possible to build a GUI or management framework to, at the very least, see what jobs are running and their current status?

Basically I need/want to have some of the functionality of Quartz (being able to stop, start, modify jobs) while using EJB 3.1 timers instead.  Trying to figure out if this is even a remote possibility or not.

Edit: As some have noted, the crux of the problem is that the timer service cannot obtain all timers for the entire container.  My idea is to create all timers within a special timer bean where all the timers can be managed.  The problem is I have no idea how to do this, or whether this is possible.  I've played with passing function pointers (as close as you can get to them in java anyway) to the timer bean along with timing parameters, but this seems really gross.

Comment: Are you using JBoss or Websphere? There's no such functionality in the JavaEE specification. If this is possible, you'd have to go with a container specific solution.

Comment: WebSphere.  Tagged JBoss as it is a problem that isn't AS specific.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [javax.ejb.TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html). Inject it into your bean:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;
```

Then, as an example, you can get iterate over all timers:

```
TimerService timerService = sessionContext.getTimerService();
for (Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
    timer.cancel(); //etc.
}
```

Comment: Its specific to a single application, not applicable to others deployed in the container.

Comment: This is specific to a single EJB bean. You can't see timers created by other beans in the same application.

Comment: @AndreRodrigues Yes, a single bean can be used to manage timers in a application, but the answer provided will not help across other applications deployed in the container, which the user is mentioning in question.